# Need a cell to recognize sheet/tab name in another cell in the same sheet, and pull a value from that sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

My first post on here. I am looking for help on a problem I have encountered at work. I need a cell to recognize the name of a tab/worksheet from another cell, and pull up a value from that worksheet. FOr example, the sheet's name is 'Destination', I want something that goes to that work sheet and pull up the value in cell C1. The value will be in the same cell in every tab, so in this example, it will always be in C1. Ideally, I'd like a formula as I have never used VBA but if there is no way around it, I'd appreciate a simple VBA code as well. 
I would like to copy this formula to multiple cells in the same column, where the name of the tab changes but the cell location does not.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a formula, use the `INDIRECT` formula. As an example, cell A1 contains the word destination. The below formula will pull information from the `Destination` Worksheet, Cell C1.

```
=INDIRECT(A1&"!C1")
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: `=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!C1")` need single quotes if sheet name has any spaces